# remove concrete dependency of two classes and access dependent objects of public constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I am usnig windsor to remove my dependency i have implimnetd below code but i am not able to access the MEthod name "test" of class "Foo"..what is the wrong thing i am doing below please let me know thanks.

**Code**

```
public interface IFoo
{
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    private readonly string _arg1;
    private readonly string _arg2;

    public Foo(string arg1, string arg2)
    {
        _arg1 = arg1;
        _arg2 = arg2;
    }

    public int test()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

class Bar : IFoo
{
    private Foo bar;

    public Bar(Foo bar)
    {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
    container.Register(Component.For<IFoo>().ImplementedBy<Foo>().LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient).Named("AFooNamedFoo"));
    container.Register(Component.For<IFoo>().ImplementedBy<Bar>().LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient).Named("AFooNamedBar").IsDefault());
    // RESOLVE A FOO
    IFoo foo = container.Resolve<Foo>("AFooNamedFoo", new { arg1 = "hello", arg2 = "world" });
    //////how to could i access foo.test();???????????????
}
```

Comment: test is method in type Foo not IFoo...why do you have IFoo empty? you need to declare test in IFoo

Comment: What concept does `IFoo` represent? Why did you design `Foo` and `Bar` to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

If you declare test method in IFoo interface then you would be able to call test method with IFoo reference (which is actually holding Foo instance)

```
 public interface IFoo
 {
    int test();
 }
```

Please note then you also have to update Bar with definition for test method otherwise your code will not compile

Comment: ..i want to ask you can we do the same with ninject without using INTERFACE...between two classes ?????

Comment: @stylishCoder are you saying you want to inject instance of Foo in class Bar without using interface...I do not think this is possible using NInject but you can pass instance of Foo in constructor of Bar..Generally interface with dependency injection come into picture when you to inject different implementation based on some condition....

Comment: ok if i pass instance of FOO in  BAR then in Ninject senario how could i access "test" method i  have use below code in ninject .please check below i am doing correct where i am wrong IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new Module());

            kernel.Bind<Foo>().To<Foo>()
      .WithConstructorArgument("AFooNamedFoo", new Foo("XXXX", "xxxx"));

            var myService = kernel.Get<Foo>();
            myService.test();

Comment: pasted code for ninject here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113015/discussion-between-stylishcoder-and-darth-wardy

Answer (score 1):

The type Bar should depend on an IFoo, it does not care what implements the interface only that an IFoo is given, IFoo should contain the int test() method you defined in Foo to allow all implementations of an IFoo to call that method and not have to know the concrete type information.

By having it directly depend on a concrete type you are potentially breaking DIP from SOLID (potentially) ... that said LSP tells us if the concrete type is abstract we could be declaring that it must be of a particular base type and we expect something to inherit that but typically in that situation Foo would be marked abstract and IFoo may not exist at all.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)

A lot of this stuff is open to interpretation on how strict you want to be with your design, generally speaking though when using IoC / Dependency Injection we would set a standard that all IoC constructed types would typically where possible only depend on Interfaces to allow us extensibility points that can be swapped out later by our IoC provider.

Depending on how you look at it an abstract base type could be looked as a "partially implemented interface", weather or not that's considered good practice I would say is likely a discussion point.

Another thing to consider:

When using IoC we are defining rules for how we construct objects in a stack, passing args for the ctor of a type means those args will always be passed unless you have an instance of your IoC container somewhere that you can define different args and apssing your IoC object down the stack you are constructing is considered an anti-pattern google for the "Service Locator Anti Pattern".

Typically you want IoC rules that don't require scalar values to be passed only objects that have their own IoC rules as best practice.

Good design tells us we should be doing something like:

- Define the components in our system / application (high level)
- Define the interfaces between components and their expected behaviour.
- Build a test plan for the expected behaviour of the interface
- Implement the interface in 1 or more concrete types
- build a rule set to select which concrete type is relevant at runtime for your IoC container

Comment: thanks for nice explanation one thing i want to ask you can we do the same with ninject without using INTERFACE...between two classes ?????

Comment: Yes ... i use ninject in my stack, it fits quite well. As a general rule though, try to use IoC only with interfaces, it should promote better design in your architecture

Comment: i want to share my code with you and want to ask a question ..where could i share with you...i have same problem with Ninject??

Comment: Looking at the code above it looks like you have 2 types that implement IFoo and you need something that builds IFoo instances, this feels like a factory pattern issue, in such a scenario I would do this: https://gist.github.com/TehWardy/72e059e7481eb0b347b4defc4b721315

Comment: ok if i pass instance of FOO in  BAR then in Ninject senario how could i access "test" method i  have use below code in ninject .please check below i am doing correct where i am wrong IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new Module());

            kernel.Bind<Foo>().To<Foo>()
      .WithConstructorArgument("AFooNamedFoo", new Foo("XXXX", "xxxx"));

            var myService = kernel.Get<Foo>();
            myService.test();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113015/discussion-between-stylishcoder-and-darth-wardy).